# Simple prediction with Keras

Tags: python, keras, predictive-modeling, prediction

I want to make simple predictions with Keras and I'm not really sure if I am doing it right. My data looks like this:

```
col1,col2
1.68,237537
1.69,240104
1.70,244885
1.71,246196
1.72,246527
1.73,254588
1.74,255112
1.75,259035
1.76,267229
1.77,267314
1.78,268931
1.79,273497
1.80,273900
1.81,277132
1.82,278066
```

Now, I want to predict `col2` by `col1` and this is how I'm doing it:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=[0, 1], header=None)
X = df.iloc[:, :-1].values.astype(np.float64)
y = df.iloc[:, -1:].values.astype(np.float64)
scalarX, scalarY = MinMaxScaler(), MinMaxScaler()
scalarX.fit(X)
scalarY.fit(y.reshape(len(y),1))
X = scalarX.transform(X)
y = scalarY.transform(y.reshape(len(y),1))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x=X, y=y, epochs=3, verbose=1)
for num in range(1, 21):
    Xnew = np.array([[float(Decimal('2.{}'.format(num)))]])
    ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
    print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
```

Comment: How many instances do you have?

Comment: about 18'000'000

Comment: And you want to predict an output which is stored int he second column using a single input variable. So the network will be doing a 1-to-1 mapping?

Comment: Whats your question exactly?

Comment: The numbers in col2 are unique. It is a series of numbers with hits and I want to predict the next possible hits (col2).

Comment: What the numbers in col1 refer to?

Comment: @MonteCristo, so you have data (hits) coming in ever 0.01 seconds, or whatever unit, and you want to predict the future hits?

Comment: temporal events where there was a hit. @JahKnows right!

Comment: Ok I do not think this is a good approach, I will show you how I would do this.

Comment: You should edit your question with this information. Right now the only answer exists because of this extra information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do here is **forecast** the future values of a time series. This is a predictive problem and the future values will depend on a number of latent factors. I will assume all we have access to is historical data from the series as your question indicates.

If you want to predict a future value for the time series, you should not only use the current value as an input, but rather you should use a chunk of the historical data. Since you have 18,000,000 instances, this is a lot, you can make your network quite complex in order to capture some latent trends hidden inside your data which can help predict the future value. To predict a value at time $t$ we will use the $k$ previous values. This hyper-parameter needs to be effectively tuned.

## Restructure the data

We will structure the data such that the features $X$ are the $k$ previous time measurements, and the output target $Y$ is the current time measurement. The one that is being estimated by the model.

```
k = 3
X, Y = [], []
for i in range(len(col1) - k):
    X.append(col2[i:i+k])
    Y.append(col2[i+k])

X = np.asarray(X)
Y = np.asarray(Y)
```

## Split your data

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)
```

## Using the data in a Keras model

This is a simple Keras model which should work as a first iteration step. However, due to the small amount of data you provided us I cannot get any meaningful results after training.

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Reshape
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.models import model_from_json
from keras import backend as K

x_train = x_train.reshape(len(x_train), k, )
x_test = x_test.reshape(len(x_test), k, )

input_shape  = (k,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.mean_squared_error,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

epochs = 10
batch_size = 128
# Fit the model weights.
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Comment: Thx, but how I do now the prediction:
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_1_input to have shape (3,) but got array with shape (1,)

Comment: I got also a very high loss:
Epoch 10/10
1218417/1218417 [==============================] - 16s 13us/step - loss: 3020611384714833.0000 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 3027083056611234.5000 - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

Comment: @MonteCristo, you need to restructure your data as mentioned above.

Comment: @MonteCristo, Can you give us access to your data please.

Comment: like this?
col1, col2 = [], []
for row in df.values:
    col1.append(row[0])
    col2.append(row[1])

Comment: yes exactly. Did it work now?